# The type 'Company.Model.User' and the type 'Company.Core.Model.User' both have the same simple name of 'User' and so cannot be used in the same model

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first, entity, entity-framework-6

I have a base entity class `MyCompany.Core.Model.User` which is to be used for common properties of a `User` entity:

```
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Usercode { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a base mapping class `MyCompany.Core.Model.UserMap` to setup the code first mappings for the base `User` class:

```
public class UserMap<TUser> : EntityMapBase<TUser>
    where TUser : User
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Usercode);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Users");
        this.Property(t => t.Username).HasColumnName("Username");
        this.Property(t => t.Usercode).HasColumnName("UserCode");
    }
}
```

In a separate assembly I have a derived class `MyCompany.Model.User` that inherits from the base `User` class and extends it with some additional properties:

```
public class User : Core.User
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

In addition I have a derived mapping class `MyCompany.Model.UserMap` to provide the additional configuration for the additional properties:

```
public class UserMap : Core.UserMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        this.Property(t => t.Surname).HasColumnName("Surname");
    }
}
```

However when adding `MyCompany.Model.User` to the context and registering the `MyCompany.Model.UserMap` I'm getting the following error:

*The type 'MyCompany.Model.User' and the type 'MyCompany.Core.Model.User' both have the same simple name of 'User' and so cannot be used in the same model. All types in a given model must have unique simple names. Use 'NotMappedAttribute' or call Ignore in the Code First fluent API to explicitly exclude a property or type from the model.*

This [link](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/03/11/ef6-nested-types-and-more-for-code-first/) indicates that you can't have the same "simple name" in the model twice.

**Why is the base class "simple name" being registered in the model, and is there a way around it in order to implement this sort of entity inheritance?**

I suspect the simple solution would be to rename the derived class; however I would prefer to avoid this as there may be many derivations in multiple contexts.

*Note: Using Entity Framework 6.0.0-rc1 (prerelease)*

Comment: Im fighting the same thing.  Did you arrive at a solution?

Comment: @JasonCragun Unfortunately no. I just went with renaming the base class to UserBase.

Comment: this problem is fixed in EF Core.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is a limitation of EF that I reported in 2012 https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/483 that is still not implemented in 6.0.2. EF uses a flat internal architecture and does not recognize namespaces. Might be coming in EF7 but not before. For now the only solutions is to rename the two classes to unique class names irrespective of the namespace they are in. IMHO, this is an significant limitation within EF. Just consider a class named Category and how many different namespaces it could be used within across a domain.

Comment: Wow, just came accross this. It's a pretty huge limitation. Pretty much wipes out the whole DDD concept of Bounded Contexts

Comment: Very annoying limitation for me. After years trying to convince myself to use EF instead NH, now stuck with this issue.

Comment: Hit this today myself. I have a system with two types of completely unrelated purchase orders, both called `PurchaseOrder`. Because of this, I need to rename one of my classes. Not pleased.

Comment: What's worse is that the table names can't be the same even if they are in different schemas.  `OM.PurchaseOrder` and `MM.PurchaseOrder` get confused by EF and it thinks they are trying to share the same table. Get it together, MS.

Comment: This issue can be less relevant if we use smaller db contexts

Comment: Fantastic. I have just run into this problem. Guess what? My class name is 'Category'.

Comment: This was addressed in October of 2013. " this is something we want to tackle post EF6 such that EF can use any number of types with the same simple name so long as they have different namespaces or outer types". Seems to me this would have been a little more important to tackle prior to EF7?
https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/03/11/ef6-nested-types-and-more-for-code-first/

Comment: 2021 and this is still and issue!!

Answer (score 4):

First read [Table type mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#2)

The hierarchical implementation model options need to be understood first.
Then look at the IGNORE option. You may or may not need depending on chosen approach.
requires ignore ???

```
modelBuilder.Ignore<BaseXYZ>()
```

Ef is currently trying to include your base class to support an included Type that inherits from a NON abstract class.

Comment: I have tried both of your suggestions. Ignoring the base class has no effect and I'm still getting the same error. Likewise, changing the base User class to be abstract has no impact.

Answer (score 0):

This happens also if you forget to explicitly add a namespace in your class. Running on EF 6.4.4 and i can differentiate through namespaces.

e.g.

```
public class MyClass {}
```

Instead of:

```
namespace somenamespace
{
   public class MyClass {}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To keep same class name I suggest to use different interfaces. An interface for the Core.Entity defining the common properties and an other interface for the extra properties. So instead of using a derived class you use a class implementing the two interfaces.

Comment: The reason for having the derived class is to minimise the duplication of entity mappings.

Answer (score -1):

if you have 2 or more classes with a relationship between them like this:

```
public class A{
public X attribute1 {get;set;}
public B b {get;set;}
}

public class B{
public X attribute1 {get;set;}
}
```

sometimes in this situation it raises this error,

Solution :
change X name in one class.

Comment: This is *never* the sole cause of this error. It can be when A refers to a different B than intended and thereby introduces the class into the entity model. But then that should be explained.

Comment: right, but it may be from compiled object reference conflict (in obj folder).