# EntityFramework how to not map a class but do map it's inherited properties

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, mapping

We use EntityFramework 6.1 with CodeFirst in our web mvc application (StdWebApp). Now we want to make a new custom version of this application (CustomWebApp) . [image: applications overview]
The CustomWebApp will use most of the code of the standard one, in it's domain model it will extend the Person class. 
In CustomDomain we make implement a new DbContext that must connect with the database of the custom app (CustomSqlDb).

In (C#) code there is no problem that there is a Person in Domain and in CustomDomain. However we have not been able to devise a mapping for Person in the Custom DbContext that will:

1. Create a single "Person" table.
2. Contains fields form "CustomDomain.Person" AND those from "Domain.Person".

We tried some variants like this:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Person");
        }
   );
```

using this document as our inspiration [msdn mapping types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/data/jj591617.aspx#2.6)

But EF complains about the simple name beeing equal.
Obviously we could rename the "Person" in "CustomDomain" to "PersonCustom" but that could lead to a lot of silly names if we have to do this again in the future like "PersonCustomExtraSpecial" etc.

Thoughts anyone?

### UPDATE

we tried the solution suggested by mr100, here is the complete code:

```
namespace Domain
{

    public class Person
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Stuff { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace CustomDomain
{   
    public class Person : Domain.Person
    {
      public string ExtraStuff { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace CustomDomain
{
    public class DbModel : DbContext
    {
       DbSet<CustomDomain.Person> Persons { get; set; }
       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
           modelBuilder.Entity<CustomDomain.Person>().Map(m => m.ToTable("Person"));
       }
    }
}
```

This still result in the error

> The type 'CustomDomain.Person' and the type 'Domain.Person' both have the same simple name of 'Person' and so cannot be used in the same model. All types in a given model must have unique simple names. Use 'NotMappedAttribute' or call Ignore in the Code First fluent API to explicitly exclude a property or type from the model.

So we added the following code:

```
namespace CustomDomain
{
    public class DbModel : DbContext
    {
        DbSet<CustomDomain.Person> Persons { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           modelBuilder.Ignore<Domain.Person>();
           modelBuilder.Entity<CustomDomain.Person>().Map(m => m.ToTable("Person"));
        }
    }
}
```

Still same result.

Comment: @Humayun Awesome edit ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this your DbContext class in CustomWebApps should have property People defined like this:

```
public DbSet<CustomDomain.Person> People {get; set;}
```

and no property:

```
public DbSet<Domain.Person> People {get; set;}
```

even if it comes from StdWebApp DbContext class from which CustomWebApp DbContext class may derive (if that is the case for you). Additionally you may set properly table name:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("Person");
```

Comment: We tried your answer, see updated question, but are still getting the same error. If it worked for you, can you include the sample code in your answer?

Comment: Unfortunately that what you are going to achieve is not possible with current version of EF. EF do not recognizes namespaces and it always includes base type to the model, you can't remove it with Ignore. Check this link for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638741/the-type-company-model-user-and-the-type-company-core-model-user-both-have-t
Guys there states that EF team will eventually remove this limitation in 7th version. For now I am afraid the only solution to your problem is to rename either Domain.Person or CustomDomain.Person class to different name.