# The type 'Module1.MyEntity' and the type 'Module2.MyEntity' both have the same simple name of 'MyEntity' and so cannot be used in the same model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638741) and know that it's a limitation of EF as of version 6, but if I understand correctly, that should only happen if both versions of MyEntity are mapped **throw the same DbContext**, which is not my case.

I have:

```
public class Module1Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Module1.MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

and then in a separate file:

```
public class Module2Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Module2.MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

All the references to this issue I've found online happen to people using **the same** DbContext. My question is, when they say "cannot be used in the same **model**", what do they mean by **model**? Isn't it the DbContext? If it is, shouldn't my code work fine?

Comment: The linked article seems to say it would happen with ANY two entities with the same name anywhere within the same application when using ModelFirst or DatabaseFirst practices.

Comment: But if "the same application" is a Web MVC/API application, then it shouldn't matter, since the DbContext and almost everything's lifespans are per-request. The Module1.MyEntity is being used from an MVC controller and the the Module2.MyEntity from an API one actually.

Comment: This supposedly happens because of the way EDMX files are handled. The only given solution is to use CodeFirst instead of the deprecated EDMX. Deprecated you ask? EDMX are no longer supported as of EF-Core

Comment: Who mentioned anything about using EDMX?

Comment: That's what DatabaseFirst and ModelFirst mean. Both of those paradigms use an EDMX file to store the entity configuration instead of Code-First fluent-api, and/or attributes. Since your code doesn't actually show any model configuration code, it's unknown what method you are using.

Comment: At work we have a web service (WCF/WebApi) that uses entities of the same name, but the old (edmx for WCF) implementation and the new (code-first for WebApi) implementation are in separate assemblies, and the service assembly references both of the implementations.

Comment: Dude, I KNOW what EDMX means! I'm using Code First!

Answer (score 0):

It should work.
If you are using different databases (connection) you don't have any problem.
If you are using the same database you have 2 different scenarios:

- If your classes have the same properties (or are the same class, you can have the same class in 2 different scenarios) you can have the same table for the two classes or you can specify different table to have distinct entities.
- If your classes are different you should specify different table names for the classes. You could also create a single table with all the columns required for the classes and disable migrations.