# EF 6.1.3 Multiple Database (MSSQL) Generic Repository "Same Table Name"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

so I have 2 different DbContext (ef 6.1.3 code first)

- FirstDbContext
- SecondDbContext

each context contains a SbSet Users that maps the user table in the corresponding database 
NOTE : the data is different, DbFirst User is not DbSecond User!!

I have an abstract repository:

```
public abstract class Repository<TContext> where TContext : DbContext
{
    public Repository(TContext ctx)
    {
    }
}
```

and 2 repositories :

```
public FirstRepo : Repository<FirstDbContext>
{
    public FirstRepo(FirstDbContext ctx):base(ctx)
    {
    }
}

public SecondRepo : Repository<SecondDbContext>
{
    public SecondRepo(SecondDbContext ctx):base(ctx)
    {
    }
}
```

I Have 2 different MSSQL databases related to the contexes:

- DbFirst
- DbSecond

I'm using dependency injection to add scoped repository and contexes, 2 database, 2 different connection.

I expected that my .Net Core application would use 2 Models
but once i get data from both the context i get

> NotSupportedException: The type 'First.User' and the type 
>   'Second.User' both have the same simple name of 
>   'User' and so cannot be used in the same model.

Why the same model?

I know that in the same model I should have different names because EF does not look for namespaces, but in that case I shouldn't have this kind of issue.

---

EDIT #1 : 
If I use one of the repository alone everything works as expected so i'm sure that there isn't any mispelled namespace
If I use the repositories all together i got this error, for example

```
var top10 = FirstRepo.GetTop10().ToList();
var sam = SecondRepo.GetByName<Second.User>("sam");
```

---

EDIT 2 (@Steve Green):

```
//Note that I'm not trying to do this : 
public class MyTextContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Test.Security.Question> Security_Question { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Test.Forms.Question> Forms_Question { get; set; }
}


// What I need is something like this :
public class SecurityContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Test.Security.Question> Question { get; set; }
}
public class FormsContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Test.Forms.Question> Question { get; set; }
}
```

Important note
If I manually ignore the "other" entity in both of the context everything works
I Remark that the context are not only in different namespaces, but also different assemblies...

```
// this is working!! .___.
// but i don't want to add a reference to a project just to exclude a class... it's unacceptable 
public class FirstDbContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<First.User> Users {get;set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Ignore<Second.User>();
    }
}

public class SecondDbContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<Second.User> Users {get;set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Ignore<First.Usere>();
    }
}
```

---

Any suggestion different from renaming the table will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Since both types are named User, are you sure you aren't mixing them up somewhere due to usings? Like declaring the DbSet in first context to be of type Second.User.

Comment: thanks for the answer, yep i'm sure that there isn't any mispelled namespaces. If I use one of the repository alone (first or second doesn't matter) everything works great, if I mix them up (with separated and reificated queries) , i get this error, it seems that instead of using 2 different models only one is created (whith 2 different connections ??? i don't undestand)

Comment: Are the user types related in any way? Do they derive from a common base class? Either way the easy thing to try is to rename one of them and explicitly map them to their table, that way you can rule out an internal conflict in EF code I guess

Comment: at the moment, every entity has the [Table] attribute provided by ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, I double checked that i don't have any cross reference. Do you think that explicit map inisde OnModelCreating would be better?

Comment: i tried renaming the User to User1 , now i get the same error on another table "Customer", that table as the table Users is available in each database, but it is present only in the FirstDbContext and NOT the SecondDbContext, it seems that issue is related with the usage of the [Table] attribute...

Comment: Appears to be a known issue. See [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/483)

Comment: Thanks Steve, I know about that issue, but my problem I think is slightly different, let me reply you inside the post (here i can't)

Comment: Your issue is indeed the same as the one pointed out by @SteveGreene. It's a known limitation with EF. Here is a little more explanation from a use-case perspective https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638741/the-type-company-model-user-and-the-type-company-core-model-user-both-have-t

Comment: thank Adam! actually ignoring the "other" class inside the context is working, but to me it doesn't make sense, did you read my reply inside the post?  it seems that the system is creating one single model instead two separated ones (as for example happened when working with twe database first models)

Comment: Yeah I saw that and quickly edited my comment! lol. The use-case I misinterpreted said they ignored the **base** class without any effect.

Comment: Personally, if EFCore has the same issue, this is enough for me to look for another OR/M

Comment: yep, I'd like too :) my next try will be to move one of the code first dbcontext into a database first one...